# exception creating a JDBC Connection Pool Glassfish v3 

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, connection, glassfish, connection-pooling

I am experiencing problems creating a connection pool in glassfish v3, 
just for reference i am using the Java EE glassfish bundle.

my enviroment vars are as follows

```
Url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
User: sys
Password : xxxxxxxx
```

which i think is all i need to make a connection. but i get the following exception

```
WARNING: Can not find resource bundle for this logger.  class name that failed: com.sun.gjc.common.DataSourceObjectBuilder
SEVERE: jdbc.exc_cnfe_ds
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
 at com.sun.gjc.common.DataSourceObjectBuilder.getDataSourceObject(DataSourceObjectBuilder.java:279)
 at com.sun.gjc.common.DataSourceObjectBuilder.constructDataSourceObject(DataSourceObjectBuilder.java:108)
 at com.sun.gjc.spi.ManagedConnectionFactory.getDataSource(ManagedConnectionFactory.java:1167)
 at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.getDataSource(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:135)
 at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:90)
 at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.getManagedConnection(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:520)
 at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.getUnpooledConnection(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:630)
 at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.testConnectionPool(ConnectorConnectionPoolAdminServiceImpl.java:442)
 at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.pingConnectionPool(ConnectorRuntime.java:898)
 at org.glassfish.admin.amx.impl.ext.ConnectorRuntimeAPIProviderImpl.pingJDBCConnectionPool(ConnectorRuntimeAPIProviderImpl.java:570)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.glassfish.admin.amx.impl.mbean.AMXImplBase.invoke(AMXImplBase.java:1038)
 at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
 at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
 at javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:288)
 at org.glassfish.admin.amx.util.jmx.MBeanProxyHandler.invoke(MBeanProxyHandler.java:453)
 at org.glassfish.admin.amx.core.proxy.AMXProxyHandler._invoke(AMXProxyHandler.java:822)
 at org.glassfish.admin.amx.core.proxy.AMXProxyHandler.invoke(AMXProxyHandler.java:526)
 at $Proxy233.pingJDBCConnectionPool(Unknown Source)
 at org.glassfish.admingui.common.handlers.JdbcTempHandler.pingJdbcConnectionPool(JdbcTempHandler.java:99)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.handler.Handler.invoke(Handler.java:442)
 at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:420)
 at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:394)
 at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.invokeCommandHandlers(CommandActionListener.java:150)
 at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.processAction(CommandActionListener.java:98)
 at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:772)
 at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
 at com.sun.webui.jsf.component.WebuiCommand.broadcast(WebuiCommand.java:160)
 at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:775)
 at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1267)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
 at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
 at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:240)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:239)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
 at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
 at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
 at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
 at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
 at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
 at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
 at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
 at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
 at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

WARNING: RAR8054: Exception while creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool [ testingManagmentDataConnection ], Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
WARNING: Can not find resource bundle for this logger.  class name that failed: com.sun.gjc.common.DataSourceObjectBuilder
```

does anyone have any ideas what i am doing wrong/ what i will have to do to 
correct this issue,

Thanks for your time
Jon

Answer (score 16):

Copy the jdbc jar to $glassfish-v3/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext/ and restart glassfish.

this should fix the problem.

Answer (score 5):

it looks like the server doesn't have the jar that contains the class oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource on the classpath.

[there are a couple methods to do this](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-7692/ghatb?l=en&a=view).

The easiest way to get the class onto the classpath is to copy the jar that hold the class into your domain's lib directory.

That is usually $glassfish-v3-install-root/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib.